# Missing my custom content type in UI List instance

Tags: visual-studio, content-type, list-definition

In visual studio I defined some content types. In addition I added each content type to a list definition and created a list instance from each list definition.
When I install my solution in SharePoint I get no errors and all list instances and content types are there. 
But when I want to add a new item to one of this list instances I can see just “New Item” and my corresponding content type doesn’t appear in UI for selecting.
When I show In list setting the content type columns are there and in all list forms appears in correct format.

Where can I have made a mistake?

Comment: if you go to the list settings page, is "Visible on New Button" ticked for the content type?

Comment: I solved the problem. Instead of using ContentType tag in list definition i user the ContentTypeRef and it works for.
 You can find a good example in [MSDN][1] 


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276355.aspx